# How import data from Redis to clickhouse

Tags: redis, clickhouse

I have a problem with connecting Redis to clickhouse. How can I get data from Redis and import it to clickhouse?

Comment: you can attach Redis-storage as [external dictionary](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-redis)

Comment: if Redis has [ODBC/JDBC connectors](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/connectors/odbc-jdbc-connectors/) use related [table engines](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/) to connecting through them.